# Java Scoping and how to perform writes to a common log file

Tags: java

How do you structure code to allow file writes from different code parts to a single log file? I thought it would be appropriate to have a single static object as the file handle, open the file once, and perform buffered writes to the file from any code section, using this static file handle.

How should the code be scoped, and how should exception handling be applied for the file writes (my attached simplified code shows multiple errors in my improper exception handling, and the static declarations seem wrong). The compiler insists on exception handling for the declaration [how?] so that exception handling can be used whenever the file handle is used (I'm totally missing something fundamental here).

Simplistically, I could choose to have every code section that needs to write to the log, merely open the file, write, and close, but that is inefficient. All examples of file writing I've seen merely bundle all open, write, close operations in a small code snippet but my file operations are distributed in multiple methods within the class.

What is the best way to declare a file handle object, and use it to write to the file from different code sections, and properly handle io exceptions?

```
public class MyApp3 {

   // create the file handle
   static FileWriter log = new FileWriter("Logfile.txt", true);  // compiler flags ERROR on this line
                                                                 // "unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown"
   static BufferedWriter bufferedLog = new BufferedWriter(log);

   static void Activity1() {
      bufferedLog.write("Activity1 actions written to log");  // compiler flags ERROR on this line
                                                              // "unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown"
   }

   static void Activity2() {
      bufferedLog.write("Activity2 actions written to log");  // compiler flags ERROR on this line
                                                              // "unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown"
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Activity1();  // performs some file writes

      Activity2();  // performs some file writes

      try {
            bufferedLog.write("Last write to file before close.");

        } catch (IOException e) {   
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            bufferedLog.close();  // compiler flags ERROR on this line
                                  // "unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown"
        }
   }

}
```

Comment: Use a logging library, but...the solution to this isn't to change how the file is opened and closed, it's to handle the IOExceptions, in whatever way is appropriate for your application.  If the file can't be written to for some reason, what do you want to do?  Skip logging?  Error out of the app?  (But you should be using a logging library.  Seriously.  You are reinventing a very complex wheel.)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the logging library - they've solved all the issues you've raised in the question.
Log4j (2), Logback are examples of libraries as such
There is even one, built-in into JDK (although nearly no one really uses it - its called JULI - search for the package `java.util.logging`)

So, in terms of these libraries, you'll have multiple loggers associated with a file appended that will write into this "single" file in an efficient manner. You'll be able to rotate this file when it reaches a certain size, the library will delete obsolete files, etc.
Also, you will be able to define the format of the message, log exceptions, and so on and so forth. Bottom line, this is something that I highly recommend to not "re-invent the wheel" and use one of the aforementioned production ready solutions